# I'm having problem with SUM() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I want to fetch the **BalanceAmt** of a particular Customer attended by a particular attender. The criteria is that a customer may buy more than one items. Each bought items has been recorded individually. At some cases '***attender***' value would be NULL.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT Customer, AttendedBy, SUM(BalanceAmt) FROM billing GROUP BY Customer 
     HAVING AttendedBy='attender' AND Customer='CustomerName'
```

My problem is I'm getting the value summed up not attended by the '***attender***' (i.e., including NULL value). 
Help me to do it..

Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling haven't gotten the question right, but I would write the SELECT Statement like this

```
SELECT Customer, SUM(BalanceAmt) 
FROM billing 
WHERE AttendedBy='attender' AND Customer='CustomerName' 
GROUP BY Customer
```

I am not sure what the AssignedTo is. If you want the sum on Customer, AssignedTo then it would be:

```
SELECT Customer, AssignedTo, SUM(BalanceAmt) 
FROM billing 
WHERE AttendedBy='attender' AND Customer='CustomerName' 
GROUP BY Customer, AssignedTo
```

Comment: Nicely put... spent too much time wrangling with my browser, but came to same conclusion as you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include a `where` clause to exclude your null values... Something like the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT Customer, AssignedTo, SUM(BalanceAmt) FROM billing 
WHERE not(BalanceAmt is null) AND AttendedBy='attender' AND Customer='CustomerName'
GROUP BY Customer, AssignedTo
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer, SUM(BalanceAmt) 
FROM billing 
WHERE AttendedBy='attender' AND Customer='CustomerName' 
GROUP BY Customer
```

In your above query `group by` is not required as you have put the column in the `where` clause.

You can remove it from `select` and you remove `group by` as well.

You can write something like this, to get the Customer-wise sum.

```
SELECT Customer, SUM(BalanceAmt) 
FROM billing 
WHERE AttendedBy='attender'
GROUP BY Customer;
```